# Struggling with Vigenere! (In C) invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int') and other things

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

we are now working with caesar, vigenere. I mannaged to finish caesar but vigenere is not working as good. C gives me back:  invalid operands to binary expression ('int *' and 'int'). I'm not sure what the program means exactly and what is wrong with my code. Can somebody help me out or give me advice? I think it's because I can not count with the different types of numbers? I'm not sure!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("You have to input a key, try again!\n");
    return 1;
}

string key = argv[1];
int keylength = strlen(key);

for (int i = 0; i < keylength; i++)
{
    if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
    {
        printf("Please insert letters, nothing else\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

printf("plaintext: ");
string plain = get_string();


int keycipher[keylength];
for(int i = 0; i < keylength; i++)
{
    keycipher[i] = toupper(key[i]) - 65;
}

if (plain != 0)
{
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    int i;
    for (i = 0, keylength = strlen(key); i < keylength; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(plain[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (plain[i] - 65 + keycipher) % 26);
        }
        else if (islower(plain[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (plain[i] - 97 + keycipher) % 26);
        }
        else if (plain[i] == ' ')
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", plain[i]);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `+ keycipher` --> `+ keycipher[index]`

Comment: plain text seems to be longer than the key, it seems to be incorrect to use key length for plaintext. So it is not possible to use indexes common to them.

Comment: Should you be asking on the cs50 site instead; also use the [edit] link...

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664480/971127)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to use `+ keycipher[index]` instead of + `keycipher`. This is because `keycipher` is an array and you need to use only one of the elements of the array at a time.

Further, you will need 2 counter variables instead of just one in the part where you find the `ciphertext`. This is because you need to increment the `plaintext` index and the `key` index in every iteration, but once the `plaintext` length crosses the `key` length, you will need to reset the key index.
If you check the specifications, you will understand what I am saying about using 2 counters.